# Adding and removing classes depending on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add and remove classes depending on the window size and resizing:

```
var windoSizing = function() {
    var $toggleClass;
    var $window = $(window);
    var $iconsContainer = $('.fragments-content > .icons-container');
    $toggleClass = ($window.width() > 769) ? $iconsContainer.addClass('mob-only') : $iconsContainer.removeClass('mob-only');
    $window.resize(function(event) {
        $toggleClass = ($window.width() > 769) ? $iconsContainer.addClass('mob-only') : $iconsContainer.removeClass('mob-only');
    });        
};
```

Do you think is there a better way to do it?

Comment: "Better" is a matter of opinion and therefore off topic for StackOverflow so I've voted to close. But I think it would be better to remove the `$toggleClass` variable, given that you only ever assign values to it but never read those values, and you could replace the ternary expression with a single call to `.toggleClass()` (which optionally accepts a boolean as a second argument). And you don't need to repeat the code to set the class initially, just chain a `.trigger('resize')` at the end. Or you could just remove all of that JS and do it with an equivalent CSS media query...

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS media queries to set styles for different screen sizes instead of JS.

```
<style>
  .icons-container { /** general styles */ }

  @media(max-width: 769px) { 
    .icons-container { /** mobile styles */ }
  }
</style>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: It is something I can do only with JS.